# Send mail thanks to the smtp service of ionos host (1and1)

Tags: php, smtp, symfony4

I have a website hosted by ionos (before it was named 1and1). This website uses the symfony 4 framework. Everything is working properly except for sending emails. I have configure my `.env` file like this:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://contact@mysite.com:password@smtp.ionos.fr:465
```

But this is not working, and I get this error:

```
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.ionos.fr [Connection timed out #110]
```

I have already tried with the 587 port (TLS), without success. Moreover, I have tried encoding the first `@` used for the username with `%40` to avoid conflict. I think the issue might come from the SMTP configuration.

Comment: You certainly have to address this question to ionos tech support.

Comment: I'm totally not sure, but seening `smtp.ionos.fr` in your env file is not what I would expect. I would expect to see one of your domains there, using your own SMTP server. The question is therefore, why `smtp.ionos.fr`? There might be a very good reason, but if it is just a guess, it could be the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. :) @KIKOSoftware I have read this: https://www.ionos.com/help/email-office/general-topics/settings-for-your-email-programs-imap-pop3/

Comment: That page is about using a given email box with an **email client**. Normally a server is not acting as a mail client, it has its own SMTP server which you should use. I'm sorry I can't be more useful, but I think you've found the problem.

Comment: Are you using cPanel or Plesk?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I didn't know those panels... :) Because I am using the ssh access to upload my file (with rsync) and creating my tables... And with one of these tools I can directly see my own smtp server ?

Comment: They are server admin tools. They simplefy the administration of your webserver and also allow you to control the mailserver on your server. Most webhosts provide you with some type of admin tool. You should have one too for your server. You can indeed control a server through SSH/FTP but a graphical user interface is easier to use.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want do use the built-in transport (https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#using-built-in-transports)? By using that you do not need to configure the SMTP connection. I tried plain https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php on our web site hosted by IONOS and the mail arrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are struggling, even after reading this:
https://www.ionos.com/help/email-office/general-topics/settings-for-your-email-programs-imap-pop3/

I used the configuration below (with the port **25**), and it works!

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.ionos.fr:25?auth_mode=login&username=emailAddress&password=myPassword
```